# phabricator libphutil functions undefined

Tags: php, phabricator

I upgraded an existing phabricator project just recently.
Apart from some issues during the upgrade process everything went fine.
But now im facing the issue that a few functions from libphutil are not defined for different applications in phabricator.

e.g.

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method AlmanacBindingPHIDType::getPhobjectClassConstant() in /var/www/clients/client0/web1/src/applications/phid/type/PhabricatorPHIDType.php on line 6`

A lot of the applications in phabricator therefore don't work, like indexing tasks etc...
The site overall is still running.

Are there any special configurations that have to be done for including the libphutil libraries?
The setup was working fine before on a version from mid august last year.

Comment: Off hand, it sounds like something didn't update properly.  Can you provide the SHAs for Phabricator, Libphutil, and arcanist that you have checked out?  I'm guessing your Libphutil is too old compared to your Phabricator version.

Comment: Did you restart Apache/PHP or PHP-FPM?

Comment: phabricator aa6c993848797d792a886b4a570f20ca897ade7e (Di, Feb 9) arcanist 57f6fb59d73994d90cd94143787424ce0fdbf73b (Mo, Jan 25) phutil f43291e99d36045bc459e5133454c0d8fd8768ea (Do, Jan 21) I did restart the Apache after the upgrade...i upgraded arcanist and libphutil with arc upgrade